# pince-fesses - meaning

Tags: sens

I have heard the following dialogue in the TV series "Marseille":

- J'en ai marre de tout ça. Les journalistes, les trucs officielles, les discours, les salamalecs avec des gens dont j'en n'ai rien à foutre. C'est lourd.
- C'est pas vrai. T'adores les pince-fesses.

Context: The Marseille mayor is telling his wife that he is fed up with his everyday life as mayor and she answers him.

What does "pince-fesses" mean?

Comment: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pince-fesses (sens 2). https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/dictionnaire/definition-pince-fesses/

Comment: @None I'm still not sure the meaning meant in the TV series context.

Comment: It perfectly fits the context. A *pince-fesses* is a formal reception, exactly the kind of events this mayor says he despises and that his wife says he actually enjoys.

Comment: Agreed. Sorry, I had missed the "sens 2" in @None's comment. Just for reference, it is the meaning C in the second link posted by None.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `pince-fesse` is a slang term for formal "dinner" / "reception" / "gala". We have several ass-related terms to describe the art of (decent) behaviour (`balais dans le...`, `cul-serré`, ...) :-)

In your context : *J'en ai marre de tout ça. Les journalistes, *les trucs officiels,* les discours, les salamalecs avec des gens dont j'en n'ai rien à foutre. C'est lourd.* 
<< trucs officiels >> is quite a pince-fesse (when you can eat there !)

Answer (score 0):

True, a "pince-fesses", is a kind of formal reception with drinks, wine & cheese stuff, where you meet various officials. But if you think to the litteral meaning of "pince-fesses", it is significant: an automatic translation would give "ass-pinching" and seems to be unrelated to the previous description.

However, when some people use that "pince-fesses" expression, they want to convey the mocking idea that this could be a place when you may meet some sexually interesting person. Generally speaking, this is a way to give a derogatory description of this type of official meeting: obviously the meeting will be so boring with so many uninteresting people that your interlocutor is mocking you by using that pince-fesses locution, because this is precisely the place where you are assured that you will not meet anybody interesting, let alone a possible sexual partner.